# Duplicated class error while adding dependencies | how remove specific class

Tags: android, gradle

i'm adding Intercom dependies to my project

```
 implementation "io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:8.+'"
```

and i receive this errors:

```
Duplicate class okio.-Base64 found in modules jetified-intercom-sdk-base-8.1.0-runtime.jar (io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:8.1.0) and jetified-okio-jvm-2.4.3.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3)
Duplicate class okio.-DeflaterSinkExtensions found in modules jetified-intercom-sdk-base-8.1.0-runtime.jar (io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:8.1.0) and jetified-okio-jvm-2.4.3.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3)
Duplicate class okio.-DeprecatedOkio found in modules jetified-intercom-sdk-base-8.1.0-runtime.jar (io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:8.1.0) and jetified-okio-jvm-2.4.3.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3)
Duplicate class okio.-DeprecatedUpgrade found in modules jetified-intercom-sdk-base-8.1.0-runtime.jar (io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:8.1.0) and jetified-okio-jvm-2.4.3.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3)
Duplicate class okio.-DeprecatedUtf8 found in modules jetified-intercom-sdk-base-8.1.0-runtime.jar (io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:8.1.0) and jetified-okio-jvm-2.4.3.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3)
Duplicate class okio.-GzipSinkExtensions found in modules jetified-intercom-sdk-base-8.1.0-runtime.jar (io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:8.1.0) and jetified-okio-jvm-2.4.3.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3)
Duplicate class okio.-GzipSourceExtensions found in modules jetified-intercom-sdk-base-8.1.0-runtime.jar (io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:8.1.0) and jetified-okio-jvm-2.4.3.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3)
Duplicate class okio.-InflaterSourceExtensions found in modules jetified-intercom-sdk-base-8.1.0-runtime.jar (io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:8.1.0) and jetified-okio-jvm-2.4.3.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3)
Duplicate class okio.-Platform found in modules jetified-intercom-sdk-base-8.1.0-runtime.jar (io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:8.1.0) and jetified-okio-jvm-2.4.3.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3)
Duplicate class okio.-Util found in modules jetified-intercom-sdk-base-8.1.0-runtime.jar (io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:8.1.0) and jetified-okio-jvm-2.4.3.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3)
```

i cannot found the rule to add to implementation to exclude this specific class okio.-Util and such. can anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: You are having jars already added and this dependency line in build.gradle will download and install jars causing duplication which is what the error says. Either remove jars to use this line in dependency or just remove this dependency to only use the jars.

Answer (score 1):

i know this way to exclude a whole package from a dependency, may be help you.

```
 // Retrofit
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion") {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an answer but it's very specific for this library, hope will help anyone.

Intercom default libraries come with some dependency inside the aar/jar. to avoid the issue there's a version without them here

https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/8716-using-transitive-dependencies-with-intercom-for-android

i ended up adding this library and everything worked.